# C# WPF x:Type Markup that includes classes that inherit a class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am working one some custom templates for a TreeView using HierarchicalDataTemplate. However, I am having issues getting it to work with a broad range of classes that inherit from a root class. It appears that the X:Type is very specific and won't trigger on classes the inherit from the class given. Below is some further information to help describe it.

1. I have a root class called `Event` that has 50+ other classes that inherit it and extend of it.
2. When I use the following `DataType="{x:Type events:Event}` , it will only work if the object is just the base class.

I would prefer not have 50+ HierarchicalDataTemplates in my XAML file, so is there any method that would make it work?

Comment: You probably don't want to depend on `XAML` and want to use `C#` code to check for the datatype and all of its base classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really the `{x:Type }` fault, it is just the way `DataTemplate` is resolved from resources. Consider using custom `DataTemplateSelector`. Quick example:

```
class ItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate EventTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(item is Event)
        {
            return EventTemplate;
        }
        // TODO: templates for other types
        return null;
    }
}
```

Data template definition:

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <local:ItemTemplateSelector x:Key="ItemTemplateSelector">
        <local:ItemTemplateSelector.EventTemplate>
            <!-- template for event -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="Event" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </local:ItemTemplateSelector.EventTemplate>
    </local:ItemTemplateSelector>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>
```

Usage:

```
<TreeView ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ItemTemplateSelector}">
</TreeView>
```